# How to completely defer loading Google reCaptcha until after the page fully loads

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, deferred-loading

I have Google reCaptcha v2 (checkbox type) installed on the website. But it's slowing down the page loading significantly on mobile even with the 'defer' attribute (based on pagespeed test). So, I want to defer its loading completely until after the page is fully loaded.

This is what the form code (where the reCaptcha is installed) looks like:

```py
    <form id="sib-form" method="POST" action="https://.........." data-type="subscription">
       <input class="input" type="text" id="FIRSTNAME" name="FIRSTNAME" data-required="true">
       <input class="input" type="text" id="LASTNAME" name="LASTNAME" data-required="true">

       <script>function handleCaptchaResponse() { 
       var event = new Event('captchaChange'); document.getElementById('sib-captcha').dispatchEvent(event); 
       } </script>  

       <div class="g-recaptcha sib-visible-recaptcha" id="sib-captcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
       data-callback="handleCaptchaResponse"></div>

       <button form="sib-form" type="submit">Subscribe</button>      
       <input type="text" name="email_address_check" value="" class="input--hidden">        
       <input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en">
    </form>
```

And this reCaptcha js file is added in the head section:

```py
    <script defer src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en"></script>
```

Even though the 'defer' attribute is used on this js file, other related files are loaded regardless. And they're the reason for the lower page speed.

How to defer the loading of this reCaptcha completely until after everything else is fully loaded?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I think you should use `IntersectionObserver` to observer the element which contains the recaptcha. When the element `isIntersecting` you can add the api script at the end of body tag

```
var io = new IntersectionObserver(
    entries => {
        console.log(entries[0]);
        if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
            var recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script');
            recaptchaScript.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en';
            recaptchaScript.defer = true;
            document.body.appendChild(recaptchaScript);
        }
    },
    {
        root: document.querySelector('.page-wrapper'),
        rootMargin: "0px",
        threshold: 1.0,
    }
);
io.observe(initForm);
```

Check more information about IntersectionObserver here:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So, I just need to remove the recaptcha api script and add your code to the end of body tag? How do I define the element that contains the recaptcha? Is there anything else that should be modified? It will be helpful if you can provide more details on this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So, I just need to remove the recaptcha api script and add your code to the end of body tag? => Yes
How do I define the element that contains the recaptcha? Is there anything else that should be modified? Just keep your code.

Answer (score 0):

To defer the loading of reCaptcha until after everything else is fully loaded, you can dynamically load the reCaptcha script using JavaScript after the page has finished loading or any other even if you think it's appropriate to your case. Here's an example how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
<!-- Move the script tag to the end of your HTML body -->
<!-- This ensures that it won't block other resources -->
<!-- Also, remove the defer attribute -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, update your form code to load reCaptcha dynamically after the page has loaded:

```
<form id="sib-form" method="POST" action="https://.........." data-type="subscription">
  <input class="input" type="text" id="FIRSTNAME" name="FIRSTNAME" data-required="true">
  <input class="input" type="text" id="LASTNAME" name="LASTNAME" data-required="true">

  <script>
    function handleCaptchaResponse() {
      var event = new Event('captchaChange');
      document.getElementById('sib-captcha').dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    // Wait for the page to fully load
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      // Dynamically create a script element for reCaptcha
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en';
      script.async = true;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
  </script>

  <div class="g-recaptcha sib-visible-recaptcha" id="sib-captcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" data-callback="handleCaptchaResponse"></div>

  <button form="sib-form" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
  <input type="text" name="email_address_check" value="" class="input--hidden">
  <input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en">
</form>
```

This modification ensures that the reCaptcha script is loaded asynchronously after the page has fully loaded, potentially improving the page speed. The async attribute is used to prevent the script from blocking other resources.

Feel free to change the document load event with any event you think it's best matches your case. Maybe DOMContentLoaded or load....